# What is my host name for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

This sounds like a stupid question, but I'm beginning in PHP and MySQL and failing at the first step, trying to connect to the database:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "ASOIAF.odb");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database";
        } else {
            echo "Connected to database";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand the first host parameter. A [yahoo help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-web-hosting/SLN20682.html?impressions=true) page said that the host should be "mysql", but when I used this it failed to connect as well. The database, ASOIAF, is in OpenDocument database format (odb), on LibreOffice Base. I'm using Uniserver to run PHP and MySQL; both are currently running. The web application is stored in Uniserver's www folder, and run on Google Chrome through localhost.

What should I be inserting in the host portion of the `connect` statement? Or have I made a more basic syntax error in the PHP code that is preventing a connection from being made?

Comment: mysqli is an API for MySQL not for other databases like LibreOffice Base.

Comment: @VMai — You can use LibreOffice Base as the frontend to a MySQL database. I presume that is what is happening here.

Comment: @Quentin Well, Leo King's got to connect to the backend not the frontend.

Comment: Okay, and how do I connect to the backend? How should I be connecting to LO Base with PHP?

Comment: @VMai — The code is trying to connect to the backend.

Comment: @Quentin But with the name of the frontend database file instead of the backend database name.

Comment: @VMai — They could be the same for all I know.

Comment: You're both confusing me. Could you explain what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction to fixing it?

Comment: @LeoKing I assumed first that you've got a LibreOffice Base database in a file named "ASOIAF.odb" that's not connected to any database of a  MySQL server. If that's the case, you can't connect to this database with the mysqli extension. Quentin assumed that you use LibreOffice as frontend for a MySQL backend. If the backend database name would be "ASOIAF.odb" then the connection call would be right. (user root with password "root")

Comment: Oh okay. Then you've got the right end of the stick, Vmai. Sorry I didn't explain better: I'm trying to use a web application as a frontend, using PHP, to interact with an LOB backend. The web app will be able to view the database, add to it, edit it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What is my host name for MySQL?

We don't know what you have called the computer you are running MySQL on.

> A yahoo help page said that the host should be "mysql"

That is specific to Yahoo Web Hosting. It doesn't sound like you are using their service, so that is inapplicable.

> I'm using Uniserver to run PHP and MySQL

That suggests the computer running the webserver running PHP and the computer running the MySQL server are the same machine. That makes `localhost` appropriate.

`localhost` is the standard name given to a computer on the private network that only it connects to. For MySQL is has a special meaning and causes the connection to be made via a socket instead of TCP/IP (which is more efficient).

> What should I be inserting in the host portion of the connect statement?

`localhost` if the above is correct.

> Or have I made a more basic syntax error in the PHP code that is preventing a connection from being made?

I can't see any syntax errors. I suspect the problem may be down to your database configuration. Have you told the MySQL server about `ASOIAF.odb`? Is that what the database is actually called inside MySQL (as opposed to just being the file that stores the configuration for LibreOffice to connection to that database).

Your biggest mistake is not using [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out what problems PHP is reporting.

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to database";
        echo mysqli_error();
```

Comment: I tried inserting the `echo mysqli_error();` but the output is the same: it doesn't tell me anything about an error.

Comment: "Have you told the MySQL server about ASOIAF.odb?" - No, I haven't. What do you mean by this? Which statement or function should I be using to bring the database into the loop?

Comment: @LeoKing — It sounds like you need to start by reading [how to set up MySQL as a backend to LibreOffice](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-connect-libreoffice-base-to-a-mysql-database/). You need to use MySQL as the database and (if you want to use LibreOffice at all) LibreOffice only as a frontend, not a complete database package in its own right.

Comment: Well I'm not opposed to using MySQL on it's own, but I'd be even more in the deep end there. LO has wizards to help me set the database up :).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a frontend? Do you mean a tool for viewing and manipulating the database? And is everything that LOB can do possible through MySQL?

Comment: The frontend is the client. It is responsible for presenting a user interface to the user, sending instructions to the database server and displaying the results to the user. The server stores the data and does operations like sorts and joins when instructed to by a client. As far as I know, the database part of LOB is considerably limited compared to MySQL.

Comment: Okay. Do you think it would benefit me more in the long run to ditch LOB and use MySQL, or to use MySQL as a proxy to LOB?

Comment: You can't use MySQL as a proxy to LOB. You can use LOB as a client to MySQL. I can't comment on how good LOB is at that as I only dabbled with it a little years ago.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the confusion: as I said to Vmai, I want to use a web application as the frontend. Whether the database is stored on LOB or MySQL probably doesn't make a difference, except that I don't understand MySQL, so it would probably be quicker to use LOB.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root");
```

Hope it will work

Comment: No, it's still failing to connect :/